# Log in form for site

Tags: cognito-forms

I am looking for a form to use for users to login to a site.

Is there a form that can be used as a log-in to a site?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a basic login form using the [Password field](http://blog.cognitoforms.com/password-protect-your-forms) (you can set a number of predefined passwords). Then, just embed your form onto its own page, and set it to [automatically redirect](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/14/building-forms/confirmation-page#redirect-url) to your website upon submission.